# Cuda accumulate lines of an image

Tags: c++, image, cuda, reduction

I have to accumulate the lines of an image stored in an array efficiently.

I've come up with a real naive solution but I'm pretty sure there's a much better way to do it with cuda.

```
__global__
void Accumulate(double *x, double *y, int height, int width)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i >= width)
        return;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        y[i] += x[j*width+ i];
    }

}
```

What would be an elegant solution to this problem ?

Comment: You are jumping in memory. That is inefficient. Maybe you could consider changing the index ordering of your image, so you could change the line to `y[i] += x[i*width+ j];`. This would be much more efficient, because the data that you are accessing in the images `x` and `y` would be contiguous. However, this might not be possible or desirable with regard to the rest of your program. Btw. what are you referring to as "lines"? Rows or columns?

Comment: PS: Another thing: Save the sum in a local variable first. Then, after the loop, write it into the array `y`. This saves you a lot of (expensive) accesses to global memory.

Comment: PPS: Float precision is much faster on consumer graphics cards than double precision. If you don't really need the extra precision, prefer `float`. This will give you a performance boost on graphics cards.

Comment: @user1488118 By lines I'm referring to rows. If I understand what you said, i'd need to transpose to sum and then to transpose again.

Comment: No, not really. (I mean kind of.) It's about how the individual elements of the 2d array are mapped to a linear array in memory. Example: x-fastest would be `x0y0, x1y0, x2y0, x3y0, x4y0, ... , x0y1, x1y1, x2y1, ...`. y-fastest would be `x0y0, x0y1, x0y2, x0y3, x0y4, ... , x1y0, x1y1, x1y2, ...`. Here `x` and `y` are row and column. It would be necessary to see the code here that allocates the arrays and fills them with data.

Comment: PS: just so I get this right: You want to sum all the pixels that are within one column, right?

Comment: @user1488118
You are right about the local variable. 
I need the double precision.

With this method I feel like I'm not using all the power of the GPU. That the sum of each column could be distributed.

Comment: @user1488118 That's right summing all the pixels within one column is the goal.

Comment: Well, you could maybe distribute the summing across multiple threads, using shared memory. I posted an answer below. I'm going to add something regarding this.

Comment: can't you rather process several columns at the same time? double is 8B, for example 4 columns = 256bits, in local variable (maybe even 8 columns)... I think this would be more friendly to cache lines (disclaimer: I have zero CUDA knowledge, just general assembly/performance, so maybe I'm completely off, but it feels just wrong to traverse the memory by columns, on normal CPU it's so bad, that if you would allocate whole local line for summing and add line-by-line to that, it would be better).

Comment: @Ped7g I know on normal CPU this isn't optimal. Let's say we are on a CPU, you were thinking of something like this ? : 

`double* sum = new double[width];
for(int i = 0; i < height*width; i++){
    sum[i%width] += x[i]; 
}`

Comment: @user3044142 yes, sort of, but your implementation would ruin it... this is not math, it's computer, unless you are 100% sure the optimizer will get rid of that modulus, you can't write it like this... and I had on mind the local stack memory, not thrashing the heap. I may add example in answer, if you are interested. (unless this was just example of principle, then yes, exactly this)

Comment: @Ped7g Well I'm always interested to learn some things. I could compare the methods by curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General Tips**

```
__global__
void Accumulate(float *x, float *y, int height, int width)
{
int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i >= width) return;
    float sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        sum += x[i*width + j];
    }
    y[i] = sum;
}
```

This is a suggestion of how the code could look after applying some improvements.

- Replaced `double` by `float`. This is much faster on most graphics cards. This is not possible if you really need the double precision. Often that's not the case though.
- Save the sum in a temporary variable `sum` before writing it into the array `y` which is located in global memory. Accesses to global memory are very expensive, try to avoid them whenever possible.

These are a few tips that might help you to speed up your code on the GPU.

**Finding the Optimal Block Size**

What also has an impact on performance is the block size. There is no optimal recommendation here. However, the total amount of threads in one block should always be divisible by 32. This is the size of one warp.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking time to answer. Regarding the index ordering, I can't change it because I'm doing multiple operations on the image where my current index ordering is necessary for the exact reason you want me to change the index ordering. 
The sum variable is indeed a good idea. And for the float I need the double precision in this particular case.

Comment: May I ask what the reason is why you need `double`? Even if you have a Tesla card, which is designed particularly for double-precision computations, it will be slower than `float`.

Comment: It's for scientific calculations according to a standard. I know it will be slower but it's not really a concern here comparing to what I'm going to gain using a GPU. I'm moving a part of the calculations to GPU, specifically I need to compute the FFT of each row then to accumulate the rows. As you can imagine, if I have an image of let's say 4000*5000, running the FFTs on the CPU compared to the batch FFT on the GPU is a no match. I figured that I would also accumulate the result inside the GPU.

Comment: I just removed some things from my answer, that I think weren't entirely correct. When thinking about it again I think the index ordering is ok as it is. Each thread from one block works on a different column. The elements they are working on are from different columns, but sequential with regard to the row. Consequently, during one instruction that is executed in parallel (i.e. one iteration of the `for` loop), the individual threads are accessing values that are contiguous in memory. It would actually be interesting to see the call site of the kernel and the block size.

Answer (score -1):

For ordinary CPU optimized solution I would use this:

```
void Accumulate(double *x, double *y, int height, int width)
{
    constexpr int line_chunk_size = 16;
    double sum[line_chunk_size];    // local stack memory for summing lines
    double* line_0_begin = x, * line_0_end = x + width;
    // for K chunks (until the less-than-chunk_size part of line is left)
    while (line_0_begin+line_chunk_size <= line_0_end) {
        double* line_b = line_0_begin;
        // copy first line[chunk] to sum[chunk] (to init local sum)
        for (int i = 0; i < line_chunk_size; ++i) sum[i] = line_b[i];
        // sum remaining lines to sum[chunk]
        for (int j = 1; j < height; ++j) {
            line_b += width;
            for (int i = 0; i < line_chunk_size; ++i) sum[i] += line_b[i];
        }
        // add sum[chunk] to global y[chunk]
        // or assign it by "=", if y is not initialized
        for (int i = 0; i < line_chunk_size; ++i) y[i] += sum[i];
        y += line_chunk_size;
        // process next chunk of lines
        line_0_begin += line_chunk_size;
    }

    // process remaining less-than-chunk values of line
    // (this part can be removed, if you have fixed widths divisible by chunk-size)
    int remaining_chunk = line_0_end - line_0_begin;
    if (remaining_chunk <= 0) return;
    // copy first line[remaining] to sum[remaining] (to init local sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < remaining_chunk; ++i) sum[i] = line_0_begin[i];
    // sum remaining lines to sum[remaining]
    for (int j = 1; j < height; ++j) {
        line_0_begin += width;
        for (int i = 0; i < remaining_chunk; ++i) sum[i] += line_0_begin[i];
    }
    // add sum[remaining] to global y[remaining]
    // or assign it by "=", if y is not initialized
    for (int i = 0; i < remaining_chunk; ++i) y[i] += sum[i];
}
```

gcc6.3 with `-O3 -std=c++14 -march=skylake-avx512` command line options will produce [this code](https://godbolt.org/g/83QUbk) (if the link doesn't work any more, just copy the routine above to godbolt.org and set up the compiler + options on your own). Which looks to me quite optimal, I tried also other chunk sizes, like 32 and 64, but then it resembling regular loop more, while 16 exhausts the xmm registers for vectorizing the chunk by unrolling it completely.

(of course adjust `-march` to your actual CPU, so the executable will work. I was just trying out whether the vectorizing on high-end works as expected).

Here is code I used to test the validity of the code above:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int width = 40, height = 20;
    double testX[width*height], testY[width] = {0};
    double* tXptr = testX;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            *tXptr = (y <= x) ? 1+x : 0;
            ++tXptr;
        }
    }
    // print testX for verification
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) std::cout << testX[y*width + x] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Y before:\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) std::cout << testY[x] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    Accumulate(testX, testY, height, width);
    std::cout << "Y after first Accumulate:\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) std::cout << testY[x] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    Accumulate(testX, testY, height, width);
    std::cout << "Y after second Accumulate:\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) std::cout << testY[x] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Please, I would appreciate any profiling/measures in real life of this, how it stands against your original CUDA implementation (this is single CPU core, but can be spread to multiple threads by chunks quite easily, although I'm not sure how much the CPU will recognize the memory access patterns are not colliding, maybe I would use several chunks per core, so core0 would do first 10 chunks of columns, core1 chunks 11..20, etc.. so each thread would start well apart of each other). I would love to hear how old CPU (with "good code" according to me ;) ) is holding up against CUDA with yours original version, just to get idea how powerful those GPUs are. Thank you (if it doesn't take too much time to do some profiling).

---

EDIT: What I did, I simply process several values from the same row at the same time ("chunk") into local sum variable, and at the end I add that to `y`. And I avoid any multiplication/division/modulus in addressing the `x`/`y` memory and overall give the compiler chance to understand what is going on, so it can optimize aggressively.

If "chunk" size would be 4, and your data would be 10x4, this is the order of accessing memory of `x`:

```
1111555599
22226666AA
33337777BB
44448888CC
```

Comment: I'll try to test it when I have some time but don't expect an answer in the next few days, I need to finish the project before anything else. I also need to understand exactly what you did there's something to learn here.

Comment: @user3044142 of course, take your time. I added some more explanation what that code does. (BTW I wonder how hard it would be to use as replacement of yours, unfortunately I don't fully grasp the `int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;` - how you define which column is to be processed, and how you run those Accumulates for all columns, which is the only thing making this not a direct replacement, rest of the routine is written in the same way as yours.

Comment: @user3044142 so, did you ever take a look on this?